# Camunda incident integration with Pagerduty

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler, pagerduty

Is there a way that we can integrate Camunda BPMN workflows with Pagerduty. I would want all the incidents to be integrated with Pagerduty. Any references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into various events via a generic listener mechanism, e.g. https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/the-spring-event-bridge/

From here you can trigger the Pagerduty REST API
https://developer.pagerduty.com/api-reference/

If you have more complex requirements or want to get fancy you could also consider a custom incident handler https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-engine/incidents/